# setting up django-admin project using cmd

Tags: python, django, admin

C:\Users\Lenovo Thinkpad\Desktop\manage> django-admin startproject cruxlore
'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Please how do I set up my Django environment for new projects, I have tried out different resources but have not gotten a positive result

Comment: Really? You couldn't find a resource on Google about how to set up a Django project/environment? Reaaaalllllyyyy?!

Comment: I tried some options and I have not gotten any result, I even had to set the path permanently but I still did not get a positive result

Comment: It took me five seconds: "The django-admin script should be on your system path if you installed Django via its setup.py utility. If it’s not on your path, you can find it in site-packages/django/bin within your Python installation. Consider symlinking it from some place on your path, such as /usr/local/bin." from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/

Comment: I already have Django installed but I have not been able to start a new project using the Django-admin command

Comment: For Windows users, who do not have symlinking functionality available, you can copy django-admin.exe to a location on your existing path or edit the PATH settings (under Settings - Control Panel - System - Advanced - Environment...) to point to its installed location.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure to [install Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/install/) correctly as described by the official [Django Tutorial01](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) :)